# How to disable CheckListBox scroll when the last item is clicked?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe7, delphi-10.2-tokyo, checklistbox

If there are enough items in the CheckListBox, so it has a scrollbar, whenever the last item is clicked it scrolls to the next one, which results in undesired behaviour:

- checking/unchecking the next item instead of the one I clicked

Tested it in both Delphi XE7 and a newer version, the 10.2 Tokyo and it does the same thing

Tried capturing the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message and track it, which resulted in finding the exact place things happen.

Vcl.Controls.pas

```
...
procedure TControl.WMLButtonDown(var Message: TWMLButtonDown);
begin
  SendCancelMode(Self);

  inherited; //there it scrolls by 1 line

  if csCaptureMouse in ControlStyle then
    MouseCapture := True;
  if csClickEvents in ControlStyle then
    Include(FControlState, csClicked);

  DoMouseDown(Message, mbLeft, []); // it does the check/uncheck
end;
...
```

Code for reproduction: (and drop a TCheckListBox on the form)

```
...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  CheckListBox1.Height := 145; //just so it's short enough
  for i := 0 to 30 do
  begin
CheckListBox1.Items.Add('Item'+IntToStr(i));
  end;
end;
...
```

Then click the chechbox of item that shows on the bottom

Also tried to go trough the unit, which contains evertything about the CheckListBox (Vcl.CheckLst, but haven't found anything usable

**EDIT**

BrakNicku discovered he could only reproduce it with partial items, which seems to be the case for me as well

His solution: Set the IntegralHeight property to True, so it prevents this problem.

Comment: *"you can skip the windowproc related things"* - Please skip it already - remove that part from the code in the question, post a reproduction case that doesn't include a weird fix attempt.

Comment: It does nothing in this case other than allowing you to enter it trough a breakpoint, but I'll remove it.

Comment: ProcessMessages while processing an input message may cause other input to be processed before the actual input.

Comment: That was insightful, thanks for the info, will pay more attention to "extra bits" when I ask questions in the future.

Comment: Possible workaround is to set`IntegralHeight` to true or adjust height so there are no partial items. I could reproduce the problematic behavior only with partial item.

Comment: @BrakNicku This seems to be a working solution, thank you very much!